# Modeling Entity relationships with GAE

Tags: java, google-app-engine

Using the native GAE DatastoreService: `com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreService`

How can you model the following relationships:

- One-to-Many
- Many-to-One
- Many-to-Many
- One-to-One